# Listing my splitted data in R

Tags: r

My data looks like this:

```
colnames(dati)< - c("grupa", "regions5", "regions6", "novads.rep", "pilseta.lt", "specialists", "limenis.1", "limenis.2", "cipari.3", "ratio", "gads", "KV", "DS")
```

and I have manually applied `split` to it in order to have 24 splits (12 splits including year and 12 without splitting by years). I did them following way:

```
k1<-split(dati$ratio, list(dati$gads, dati$grupa), drop=TRUE)
k2<-split(dati$ratio, list(dati$gads, dati$grupa, dati$regions5), drop=TRUE)

...

k13<-split(dati$ratio,list(dati$grupa),drop=TRUE)
k14<-split(dati$ratio,list(dati$grupa,dati$regions5),drop=TRUE)
...etc
```

and what I mean to do is to apply these splits to my function as follows:

```
function(k1,k13)
```

but instead of inserting the values manually I would like to change them so that I could do my function similar to this:

```
for(i in 1:12){function(k[i],k[i+12])}
```

I just can't seem to find the right way to do it

`dati` after i split them look like this:

```
      grupa regions5 regions6 novads.rep pilseta.lt specialists
1    1* Zemgales Zemgales     Novads      lauki       Silva
2    1* Kurzemes Kurzemes     Novads      lauki     Sniedze
3    3* Kurzemes Kurzemes        REP    pilsēta      AnitaE
4    1* Vidzemes Vidzemes     Novads    pilsēta      Dainis
       limenis.1   limenis.2 cipari.3     ratio gads    KV
1  Jelgavas nov. Svētes pag.        1 0.8682626 2011  2162
2 Ventspils nov. Vārves pag.        1 0.3923857 2011 27467
3       _Liepāja    _Liepāja        4 0.4069100 2011 30107
4  Alūksnes nov.     Alūksne        2 0.5641127 2011  8147
        DS
1  2490.03
2 70000.00
3 73989.33
4 14442.15
...
```

and here is the output i'm looking for:

```
                   count        mean     lowermean  uppermean     median ...
2011.1*.Kurzemes    119  0.83322820  7.719323e-01  0.8945241 0.79888324
2012.1*.Kurzemes    171  0.82800498  7.836221e-01  0.8723879 0.84424821
2013.1*.Kurzemes    144  0.77551814  7.347631e-01  0.8162731 0.80745150
2014.1*.Kurzemes    180  0.78134649  7.396007e-01  0.8230923 0.81635065
2015.1*.Kurzemes     80  0.78146588  7.135070e-01  0.8494248 0.73659659
2011.10*.Kurzemes    16  1.09552970  6.930780e-01  1.4979814 1.02127841
2012.10*.Kurzemes    22  0.87442906  5.721409e-01  1.1767172 0.74787482
2013.10*.Kurzemes    25  0.84406131  6.947097e-01  0.9934129 0.91786319
2014.10*.Kurzemes    22  0.79385199  5.880507e-01  0.9996533 0.71708060
2015.10*.Kurzemes    12  1.19059850  8.213604e-01  1.5598365 1.25322750
2012.11*.Kurzemes     1  0.09461065            NA         NA 0.09461065
2013.11*.Kurzemes     2  0.18134522 -1.823437e+00  2.1861274 0.18134522
2014.11*.Kurzemes     1  0.11097174            NA         NA 0.11097174
2013.12*.Kurzemes     1  0.44620780            NA         NA 0.44620780
...
```

Comment: Could you construct a sample `dati` with desired output so we can understand what you are going for.

Comment: Please edit your title to something useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a list:

```
k <- list()
k[[1]] <- split(dati$ratio, list(dati$gads, dati$grupa), drop=TRUE)
k[[2]] <- split(dati$ratio, list(dati$gads, dati$grupa, dati$regions5), drop=TRUE)
# etc
```

Then the following is valid:

```
for(i in 1:12){
    function(k[[i]],k[[i+12]])
}
```

Note that `k3` is the name of a variable, which could be `x`, `myvar32`, whatever. When you type k[3], you state that you want to access the third cell of the vector `k`. Note that `k` and `k3` are totally distinct variables. If you want to be able to access you variables using `k[i]`, you must first create the vector k and store what you need in `k[i]`...

The double bracket notation is used to access lists, which are basically handy store anything -- what you need in your case.